# RxJS observable which emits both previous and current value starting from first emission

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) which emits JavaScript objects periodically. I want to construct another observable which will emit both previous and current values of the underlying observable in order to compare two objects and determine the delta.

The [`pairwise()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pairwise) or [`bufferCount(2, 1)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferCount) operators are looking like a good fit, but they start emitting only after buffer is filled, but I require this observable to start emitting from the first event of the underlying observable.

```
subject.someBufferingOperator()
    .subscribe([previousValue, currentValue] => {
        /** Do something */
    })
;
```

> On first emission the `previousValue` could be just `null`.

Is there some built-in operators that I can use to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 112):

Actually, it was as easy as pairing [`pairwise()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pairwise) with [`startWith()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-startWith) operators:

```
subject
    .startWith(null) // emitting first empty value to fill-in the buffer
    .pairwise()
    .subscribe([previousValue, currentValue] => {
        if (null === previousValue) {
            console.log('Probably first emission...');
        }
    })
;
```

Comment: What if the previous or current value is `null` but it's not the first emission. How to detect it?

Comment: @FARID I believe you could `startWith(new Symbol('First emission'))` if you really need such determinism, or just use a flag for this.

Comment: Not a very TypeScript-friendly solution, unfortunately. Now both `previousValue` and `currentValue` have type `... | null`. Is there a way to not add `null` to `currentValue`'s type?

Comment: @thorn̈ you could always manually cast the observable to the required type, e.g. `as Observable<[null | Type, Type]>`.

Comment: @thorn0 that's because you have strict=true  in your tsconfig. The last 4 companies I worked for had strict=false. Everything still perfectly typed, but you just never need to add `| null`.  Just something to consider.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a simple operator:

```js
function withPreviousItem<T>(): OperatorFunction<
  T,
  {
    previous?: T;
    current: T;
  }
> {
  return pipe(
      startWith(undefined),
      pairwise(),
      map(([previous, current]) => ({
        previous,
        current: current!
      }))
    );
}
```

The nice thing about this is that the result has meaningful property names and correct types:

- `previous` is `T | undefined`
- `current` is `T` (not `T | null`)

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3i1nsg?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the snippet for rxjs 6+

```
subject
    .pipe(
       startWith(undefined),
       pairwise()
    )
    .subscribe(([previousValue, currentValue]) => {
        /** Do something */
    });
```

The value in `startWith()` should be `undefined` because there is no value. Typically `null` is defined as "we have a value and this value is empty".

Answer (score 4):

`scan` (RX equivalent of a reduce) is an option here:

```js
subject
    .scan((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        const previousValue = ...accumulator.slice(-1);
        return [previousValue, currentValue];
    }, [null]) // emitting first empty value to fill-in the buffer
    .subscribe(([previousValue, currentValue]) => {
        // ...
    });
```

This can be extended to a more general case when you want to look at more than two items.