# How can I compare the length of an Observable<any[]> array with previous one?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, observable

So I have a service http function which return an Observable<any[]>. I call this function every minute in the component and I want to compare the length of the previously returned array with the length of the newly returned array.How can I do this?

This is the service method:

```
public getMatchIncident(matchId: number): Observable<any[]>{
    return  this.http.get<any>(this.url + matchId);
}
```

This is the component function:

```
private getMatchIncident(matchId: number): void {
    this.matchService.getMatchIncident(matchId).subscribe(event => {
      const previousLength = this.incidents.length;
      const newLength = event.length;
      this.incidents = event;
    });
}
```

But it doesn't work well...
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059622/rxjs-observable-which-emits-both-previous-and-current-value-starting-from-first)

Comment: Why does it not work well? Between the possible duplicate and the lack of details I think it's reasonable to close this.

Comment: The previousLength  and the previousLength are the same